# Python pandas unindo planilhas que estão dentro de um array

Tags: python, pandas, xls

Comunidade, eu tenho um diretório que contém várias planilhas ".xls" e gostaria de unir essas planilhas em um único DataFrame e como bônus exportar esse novoDataFrame em ".xlsx".

Estou usando o for para percorrer o diretório em busca dos arquivos ".xls" salvo eles na variável files_xlsx e gostaria de juntar (merge) dessas planilhas, segue o código abaixo:

```
from numpy import append
import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
path = r'/Users/danilobrun/Downloads/temp/pandasimovelacao'
files = os.listdir(path)

files_xlsx = [path + '/' + f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']
print(files_xlsx)
for f in files_xlsx:
    data = pd.read_excel(f)
    df = pd.merge(data, data, how = 'outer')
    
print(f'Meu DataFrame completo {df}')
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Caso a resposta fornecida tenha resolvido o problema apresentado, considere por favor clicar no botão ✔ para aceitar a resposta, por favor.

Answer (score 2):

****Resposta adaptada e traduzida do Stack Overflow em inglês****
[Import multiple excel files into python pandas and concatenate them into one dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20908339/12195738)

Um exemplo usando 5 arquivos Excel idênticos que são anexados ("*appended*") sequencialmente.

**(1) Imports**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
```

**(2) Listando arquivos:**

```
>>> caminho_atual = os.getcwd()
>>> arquivos = os.listdir(caminho_atual)
>>> print(arquivos)
['.DS_Store',
 '.ipynb_checkpoints',
 '.localized',
 'Screen Shot 2013-12-28 at 7.15.45 PM.png',
 'test1 2.xls',
 'test1 3.xls',
 'test1 4.xls',
 'test1 5.xls',
 'test1.xls',
 'Untitled0.ipynb',
 'Werewolf Modelling',
 '~$Random Numbers.xlsx']
```

**(3) Filtrar por arquivos 'xls':**

```
>>> arquivos_xls = [arquivo for arquivo in arquivos if arquivo[-3:] == 'xls']
>>> print(arquivos_xls)
['test1 2.xls', 'test1 3.xls', 'test1 4.xls', 'test1 5.xls', 'test1.xls']
```

**(4) Inicializar dataframe vazio:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

**(5) Iterar sobre lista de arquivos para anexá-los ("*append*") ao dataframe vazio:**

```
for arquivo in arquivos_xls:
    dados = pd.read_excel(arquivo, 'Sheet1')
    df = df.append(dados)
```

## Saída

### **xlsx**

```
df.to_excel('dataframe_mesclado.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

### **stdout**

```
>>> print(df)
  Result  Sample
0      a       1
1      b       2
2      c       3
3      d       4
4      e       5
5      f       6
6      g       7
7      h       8
8      i       9
9      j      10
0      a       1
1      b       2
2      c       3
3      d       4
4      e       5
5      f       6
6      g       7
7      h       8
8      i       9
9      j      10
0      a       1
1      b       2
2      c       3
3      d       4
4      e       5
5      f       6
6      g       7
7      h       8
8      i       9
9      j      10
0      a       1
1      b       2
2      c       3
3      d       4
4      e       5
5      f       6
6      g       7
7      h       8
8      i       9
9      j      10
0      a       1
1      b       2
2      c       3
3      d       4
4      e       5
5      f       6
6      g       7
7      h       8
8      i       9
9      j      10
```

**OBS:** Pode ser necessário ter que instalar o módulo `xlsxwriter` para escrever o arquivo "dataframe_mesclado.xlsx". Para isso basta executar o seguinte comando do **pip**:

```
python -m pip install -U xlsxwriter
```

**EDIT:** Conforme comentado pelo @AugustoVasques, a partir da **versão 1.4.0 do pandas** o método [`pandas.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) foi depreciado portanto o método recomendado agora é [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append):

***** *Revisão dos **passos (4)** e **(5)*** *****

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(arquivo, 'Sheet1') for arquivo in arquivos_xls)
```